# jQuery menu with CSS sprite

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery menu which works fine, I want to add a CSS sprite so that when 'li' is closed it has a plus sign and when it is expanded it has a minus sign.

Any suggestions based on the code below please?

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#sidenav > li > ul, #sidenav > li > ul > li > ul').hide();

$('#sidenav > li').click(function(){
$ul = $(this).children('ul').slideDown('slow');
$('#sidenav > li > ul').not($ul).slideUp('slow');
});

$('#sidenav > li > ul > li').click(function(){
$ul = $(this).children('ul').slideDown('slow');
$('#sidenav > li > ul > li ul').not($ul).slideUp('slow');
}); 
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="sidenav">
<li class=""><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li class=""><a href="#">Submenu 1</a>     
            <ul>            
                <li>Submenu-1A</li>
                <li>Submenu-2A</li>                    
            </ul>        
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>      
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu-1A</li>
                <li>Submenu-2A</li>                    
            </ul>            
        </li>
        <li>Submenu 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class=""><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Submenu 1</li>
        <li>Submenu 2</li>
        <li>Submenu 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class=""><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Submenu 1</li>
        <li>Submenu 2</li>
        <li>Submenu 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class if the li is active and define styles accordingly:

Something like this:

```
li{
   background: url(...) no-repeat 0 0;
}

li.active{
   background-position:20px 0; <- adjust accordingly
}
```

also add the clickhandler to toggle classes:

```
$('#sidenav > li').click(function(){
   ...
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

You could rewrite your clickhandler to take the whole fuzz out of your code:

(untested)

```
$('#sidenav li').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("active")
          .children("ul").toggleSlide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some class like `active` when your li wan clicked and remove it when for example with

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

and in css display plus image when it is normal and minus image when it is `active`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of checking whether if it has +  or - with the help of html() 
In that span i have '+' symbol first

```
jQuery("id").toggle();
    var cur_symbol = jQuery('id span').html();
     if(cur_symbol == ' + '){jQuery('id span').html(' - ');}
     else{jQuery('#more_opt span').html(' + ');}
        });
```

Comment: hi it looks rather a bit more complicated for its purpose but I will look into this too, I am always interested in achieving the same result through different approaches....

Comment: quite nice, except the OP wanted to use sprites. I would prefer: `jQuery('id span').html( (cur_symbol === "+")?"-":"+") );`